# Excel says: "Excel file is not a valid file extension or format type..."

Tags: java, apache-poi, excel-2019

I am using apache.poi to make an excel file, but when I generate it with a simple java code when I'm trying to open with Microsoft Excel, it says that this file cannot be opened because my file format or extension not valid.

I'm using the latest poi, and Micrisoft Office 2019 32-bit.

```
package com.company;

import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

        // An output stream accepts output bytes and sends them to sink.
        OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Geek.xlsx");

        // Creating Sheets using sheet object
        Sheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("Array");
        Sheet sheet2 = wb.createSheet("String");
        Sheet sheet3 = wb.createSheet("LinkedList");
        Sheet sheet4 = wb.createSheet("Tree");
        Sheet sheet5 = wb.createSheet("Dynamic Programing");
        Sheet sheet6 = wb.createSheet("Puzzles");


        System.out.println("Sheets Has been Created successfully");

        wb.write(fileOut);
    }
}
```

I build it, works fine, but it makes a wrong file! What might I have done wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you are using an old version of Excel that doesn't support .xlsx files?..

Comment: Now I'm installed Microsoft Office 2019, but another thing I have made file with the excel and it makes xlsx file with no problem.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use like this.

`Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();` // <--- for creating Geek.xlsx file

`Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();` // <--- for creating Geek.xls file

Answer (score 0):

At least if somebody meet with this problem I have resolved the problem with changing the file extension in the java code with *.xls extension (this format type is the older excel files type) and it goes like charm.

U.i.: Thanks Avi Meltser